# Combine logging and tracing with AspectJ

Tags: logging, aop, aspectj

Firstly, I'd like to define the difference between tracing and logging as stated in book "AspectJ in Action", p.257:

> Most developers (and this book) refer to **logging** as an ***act of producing messages specific to the logic carried by a piece of code***.
>
> **Tracing** is commonly considered as the ***act of producing messages for lower-level events***: method entry and exits, object construction, excep-tion handling, state modification, and so on.

So, with AspectJ tracing is not really hard. But, *how logging can be made consistent with AspectJ tracing*?

For example, I use sl4j logger for tracing in aspects, and I need to use **the same logger** for logging.

One of solutions is to write separate aspect that will look like this:

```
around(): catchCallToLogger(): *pointcut that intercepts calls like log(), debug(), info() etc from some logging toolkit* {
   *call logger from tracing aspect*
}
```

So, this option is acceptable, but I'd like to know whether there are alternatives to this method and whether combining tracing and logging is needed in real world.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What you seem to have in mind sounds pretty illogical, but maybe I just misunderstood. How should intercepting calls to the logging framework help you modularise the logging itself?

Comment: It won't modularize logging, but it will create the ability to change logging framework. Something like bridge from one framework to another without changes in code. Or, if multiple modules use different logging frameworks, intercepting the calls can unify them to one standard style/framework. That's how I see this. Maybe I'm wrong in my suggestions.

Comment: Now I understand your intent a bit better. Actually refactoring your logging code would be more adviseable than intercepting calls to obsolete or unwanted logging frameworks and re-routing them to the framework of your choice. But it is possible. You just won't get rid of your old library dependencies that way, because the calls to them will remain scattered across your code base. But as a quick fix this can work. If you refactor all code to use SLF4J, you can change the underlying framework on the fly because it is pluggable, but that is beyond the AspectJ topic.

Comment: Just found out that SLF4J has migrator tool. Actually, this is mostly what I needed. kriegaex, thanks for help